# TA-Lib not writing to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, ta-lib

Currently, I have a very basic pandas data frame of stock market aggregate data with 2 indexes, one which represents the ticker of the stock named `symbol` and another that represents the timestamp at which the datapoint was recorded at named `timestamp`. It looks something like this.

```
                                      open    high       low     close
symbol timestamp                                                         
AAPL   2023-07-17 09:30:00+00:00  190.9600  190.96  190.9600  190.9600   
       2023-07-17 09:31:00+00:00  190.9600  190.96  190.9600  190.9600   
       2023-07-17 09:32:00+00:00  190.9600  190.96  190.9600  190.9600   
       2023-07-17 09:33:00+00:00  190.9900  190.99  190.9900  190.9900   
       2023-07-17 09:34:00+00:00  190.9900  190.99  190.9900  190.9900   
...                                    ...     ...       ...       ...   
TSLA   2023-07-17 15:56:00+00:00  287.3200  287.47  287.2201  287.2500   
       2023-07-17 15:57:00+00:00  287.2364  287.74  287.2364  287.4959   
       2023-07-17 15:58:00+00:00  287.4800  287.84  287.4500  287.7600   
       2023-07-17 15:59:00+00:00  287.7500  287.96  287.6701  287.8401   
       2023-07-17 16:00:00+00:00  287.8501  287.90  287.5301  287.5600
```

I am trying to use TA-Lib to calculate different technical indicators of the data, but it appears that TA-Lib is unable to write to the dataframe for some reason. The following code is intended write aroon oscillator values to the column `aroonosc` but it does not appear to be writing any.

```
for symbol in self.symbol_groups.groups.keys():
    self.frame.loc[symbol, 'aroonosc'] = talib.AROONOSC(self.frame.loc[symbol, 'high'], self.frame.loc[symbol, 'low'])
```

When writing to a temporary variable, ta-lib appears to work fine, so I believe it is an issue with my usage of the pandas library.